# Can't access mapped port (can't connect from host to sshd running inside docker container)

Tags: docker

Steps to reproduce:

- HOST: docker run -t -i -p 22:1200 myimage /bin/bash
- GUEST: bash# service sshd start
- HOST: docker ps -l
- HOST: docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' container_id
- HOST: ssh -p 1200 root@container_ip_from_previous_command
- RESULT: Can't access mapped port (can't connect to sshd running inside docker container)

My host computer is running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. Docker version 1.1.2, build d84a070
I can connect from inside the docker container to sshd running on localhost port 22. I've tried with ufw disabled (has forwarding enabled) as well, same results.

Comment: I believe you are trying to route your `HOST` main interface port 1200. If you're connecting on the Docker interface you should be able to just SSH to port 22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the `-p` switch on `docker run` will only route a port off of the Docker interface. For example you will have two interfaces, `docker0` and `eth0`, you can route port 1200 from `eth0` to port 22 on `docker0`.

If you're connecting on the private interface `docker0`, there is no need to route external ports and you can just connect on port 22 (To the IP provided with `docker inspect`).

Lastly, you have the port order wrong (assuming SSH is on port 22 in the container). You should use `-p external:internal` where `external` is the port you want to expose to the World, and `internal` the relevant port within the container.